# VBA to HTML: Edit drop down

Tags: html, excel, vba, automation, dropdown

I made a simple script that takes values from excel to update a web form.

Here is the code:

```
Sub AutofillDefects()

    Dim IE As Object
    
    Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://share.amazon.com/sites/iQuality%20-%20Compliance%20Quality%20Hub/Lists/Appeals%20QA/Item/newifs.aspx?List=d543d1cd%2D5a02%2D44dd%2D979c%2Db16eeeeb9533&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fshare%2Eamazon%2Ecom%2Fsites%2FiQuality%2520%2D%2520Compliance%2520Quality%2520Hub%2FLists%2FAppeals%2520QA%2FAllItems%2Easpx&RootFolder=&Web=e53ba52a%2D0a1a%2D4ce5%2D9b10%2D1b7eacd99b79"
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl33_g_77798cac_dd9e_4abd_855e_86f279f1ef7c_FormControl0_V1_I1_T1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AC12")
    IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl33_g_77798cac_dd9e_4abd_855e_86f279f1ef7c_FormControl0_V1_I1_T2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AD12")
    
    





End Sub
```

So far this script works great when entering values inside text boxes.
The issue arises when interracting with a drop down window, where in which i tried pretty much everything.
I see that the solution is to call a change event, and select the index But i cant seem to find a way!!!
If there was a solution, is there a way to select an option in a drop down based on matching values instead of index?

Here is the html source:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "interacting with a drop down window"?  Do you mean that your VBA code can set the value of a text-box successfully, but it is not changing the selected option on the SELECT control when you do the same getElementById('dropdown').value = cell value?

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if you'll see a different result if you actually have .Value on the end of your .Sheets("Audits").Range("AC12")?  I know that .Value is essentially the assumed default, but just curious whether you would see different behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind,

Here is the solution to my problem:

Here is the code that works for drop down windows:

```
        IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_77798cac_dd9e_4abd_855e_86f279f1ef7c_FormControl0_V1_I1_D5").Focus
        IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_77798cac_dd9e_4abd_855e_86f279f1ef7c_FormControl0_V1_I1_D5").selectedIndex = 2
        IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_77798cac_dd9e_4abd_855e_86f279f1ef7c_FormControl0_V1_I1_D5").FireEvent ("onchange")
```